# Custom property's getter and setter with c++ struct array in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties

I've got an c-struct array, and want to define a property.
Here is the relative code..

```
struct Vertex {
    float x, y, z;
    float nx, ny, nz;
    float u, v;
};

@interface Mesh : NSObject{
    Vertex m_vertices[MaxVertices];
}
@property (nonatomic) Vertex m_vertices[MaxVertices];
@end

@implementation Mesh;
@synthesize m_vertices[MaxVertices];
@end
```

I first wrote like this with an error.
how to set the property with c-struct array, or customlize the setter and getter?
Any tips will be appreciated!

Comment: Objective-C is no C++. Try not to optimize on stuff which isn't really necessary. Cocoa provides so much well written API's, do use them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a close as I could get.

```
typedef struct _Vertex {
float x, y, z;
float nx, ny, nz;
float u, v;
} Vertex;

#define MaxVertices 5

@interface Mesh : NSObject{
    Vertex m_verticesX[MaxVertices];
    Vertex *m_vertices;
}
@property (nonatomic) Vertex *m_vertices;
@end

@implementation Mesh;
@synthesize m_vertices;
- (Vertex *)m_vertices
{
    if (!m_vertices)
        m_vertices = m_verticesX;
    return m_vertices;
}
@end
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
@property (nonatomic) Vertex *m_vertices;
```

and

```
@synthesize m_vertices;
```

instead. You can't use a static array like this; malloc() it using something like this in your constructor and free() in the destructor:

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        m_vertices = malloc(sizeof(*m_vertices) * NUM_OF_VERTICES);
    }
    return self;
}

- (oneway void)dealloc
{
    free(m_vertices);
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: But,how to access the element in m_vertices with something like m_vertices[i]?

Comment: Exactly, as `m_vertices[i]`. You should really read some C guides if you don't know that pointers can be subscripted just like arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use arrays as properties.  You can do two things:

1) Use a NSArray or NSMutableArray to hold objects instead of structs.

or

2) Put the array in a structure:

```
typedef struct VertexArray
{
    struct Vertex m_vertices [MaxVertices];
};

@property (nonatomic, assign) VertexArray* m_vertices;
```

or

3) Put the array in an object

```
@interface VertexArray
{
    struct Vertex m_vertices [MaxVertices];
}

- (struct Vertex)getVertexofIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)setVertex:(struct Vertex)vertex atIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

and for the property in Mesh:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) VertexArray* m_vertices;
```

or you can put the contents of VertexArray directly within Mesh (i.e. the member variable and two accessor methods).

Answer (score 0):

When you return an array of (any type) in C, you are returning the first index of the array.

So if I wanted to return the variable below that was declared in the interface.

```
 Vertex m_vertices[MaxVertices];
```

I could say...

```
- (Vertex *)m_vertices
{
    return m_vertices;
}
```

This above is the same thing as saying...

```
- (Vertex *)m_vertices
   {
       return &m_vertices[0];
   }
```

If you wanted to return the entire array back however, the best way to do this would probably be to use memcpy directive.

```
memcpy(<#void *#>, <#const void *#>, <#size_t#>)
```

Reference it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

Write the function like this...

```
- (Vertex *)m_vertices
{
   Vertex *localVertex;
   memcpy(localVertex,&m_vertices,sizeof(Vertex)* MaxVertices);
   return localVertex;
}
```

This copies the literal bytes over and is very fast.  It will return the entire array back.

The better way to do this would be to make a function like this possibly as well.

```
- (Vertex *)m_vertices_nthIndex:(int)index
{
   return(&m_vertices[index]);
}
```

This way you can get the index of whatever item you need.